BCS/Kitaev model for $p$-wave superconductivity spectrum inconsistency?
I am quite confused about the diagonalisation of the model when we use matrices to represent it. Let me illustrate, this is the Hamiltonian to diagonalise:
$$
    H_\text{BCS} = \sum_k \epsilon_k d^\dagger_k d_k - \left( \Delta e^{-ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_{N-k} + \Delta^* e^{ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_{N-k}^\dagger d_{k}^\dagger \right), 
$$
which can be represented as
$$
    H_\text{BCS} \equiv \sum_k \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 d^\dagger_k & d_{N-k} \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \epsilon_k/2 & \Delta^* e^{ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} \\
 \Delta e^{-ik\frac{2\pi}{N}}  & -\epsilon_k/2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 d_k \\
 d_{N-k}^\dagger \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
since $\epsilon_k = \epsilon_{N-k}$. That's great, we can diagonalise that to find the spectrum
$$
\begin{equation*}
\lambda_k = \pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{ \epsilon_k^2 + 4 |\Delta|^2}.
\end{equation*}
$$
But hang on!
Following for instance this other PSE question, I can also write it like
$$
    H_\text{BCS} \equiv \sum_k \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 d^\dagger_k & d_{N-k} \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \epsilon_k/2 &  -2i\Delta^* \sin(k\frac{2\pi}{N}) \\
  2i\Delta \sin(k\frac{2\pi}{N}) & -\epsilon_k/2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 d_k \\
 d_{N-k}^\dagger \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
now with spectrum
$$
\lambda_k = \pm \sqrt{ \epsilon_k^2 + 4 |\Delta|^2\sin\left(k\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)^2 }.
$$
What's going on?

I guess the lower left element in the second way of writing $H_\mathrm{BCS}$ in a matrix form shouldn't have the exponential factor?

@Anyon that's right, well spotted, that's a typo. I'll edit that

So after a week of fighting with this I found an answer to my question, let me share it for the future learners.

In line with what @mikestone pointed out, there is a symmetry concern, in the mathematical sense, of my expression. Let me explicitly, line by line, show what I mean. We can see this with only one of the sums:
$$
\sum_k \Delta e^{-ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_{N-k} = -\sum_k \Delta e^{-ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_{N-k} d_k = -\sum_k \Delta e^{-i(N-k)\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_{N-k}= -\sum_k \Delta e^{ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_{N-k}.
$$
That is,
$$
\sum_k \Delta e^{-ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_{N-k} =  -\sum_k \Delta e^{ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_{N-k},
$$
which is a wierd equation to look at in the first place. But by rewritting it, it becomes much more clear:
$$
\sum_k \Delta \left(\cos\left(k\frac{2\pi}{N}\right) + i\sin\left(k\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)\right) d_k d_{N-k} =  -\sum_k \Delta \left(\cos\left(-k\frac{2\pi}{N}\right) + i\sin\left(-k\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)\right) d_k d_{N-k},\\
\implies \sum_k \Delta \cos\left(k\frac{2\pi}{N}\right) d_k d_{N-k} = 0.
$$
That is, the only non-zero term of that sum really is just the sine part. The cosine sum is just zero. This amounts to
$$
\sum_k \Delta e^{-ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} d_k d_{N-k} = -\sum_k i\Delta \sin\left(k\frac{2\pi}{N}\right) d_k d_{N-k}.
$$
With this, the rest of the calculation follows.
Note that I dont see how this has anything to do with @Gec's answer although, admitedly, I couldnt follow it with ease. Regardless, this little calculation is just a direct consequence of @mikestone's general expression although it was hidden in the notation since it wasn't clear what the $\Delta_{ij}$ matrix was.
Lastly, just so that there is not a millimetre of room for confusion, note that that missing this out implies that the cosine part, which is zero, cancels out the sine part, which is non-zero. By "part" here I mean the entire sum with the $d_k d_{N-k}$ terms too, of course this wouldnt be true for the complex coefficients on their own.

This "answer" does not answer your own original question. You only showed that $exp(ik)$ in the Hamiltonian can be replaced by its imaginary part, due to the properties of fermion operators and the index renaming trick. This just means that there are different equivalent ways to write the Hamiltonian. But any Hermitian (and most non-Hermitian) matrix can be diagonalized. Each such diagonalization corresponds to a way to write the Hamiltonian in formally diagonal form. But these forms are not equivalent, and most of them are not diagonal. This is what I was talking about in my answer.

@Gec, this isnt an equivalent way of rewritting anything, my answer shows that the cosine part vanishes: in general $\exp(ik)\neq 2i\sin(k)$, no? On the other hand, addressing your other comments, any non-degenerate hermitian matrix has a unique eigendecomposition (up to reordering the igenvectors, which is trivial). Clearly, if the eigenvalues of the 2x2 hermitian matrix above come in $\pm$pairs, then only when $\lambda_k=0$ you have a degenerate matrix with a non-unique diagonalisation. Outside of this $\lambda_k=0$ region, the diagonalisation is unique and correctly given by my approach.

Your original question formulation is about two different but equivalent ways to write the Hamiltonian in the form of the sum of matrix elements of 2x2 matrix on operator-valued vectors. And my answer is about this particular way to write the Hamiltonian. And there actually are infinitely many more ways to write the Hamiltonian in a similar way with different Hermitian matrix. But if you want to stick to the trivial fact $\sum_k e^{ik}d_kd_{-k} = i\sum_k \sin(k)d_kd_{-k}$, then I have nothing more to say. Buy the way, your last formula in this answer is wrong. There should be minus and no 2.

@Gec Thanks for spotting that typo! My question was: Why there seems to be two, a priori, equivalent ways to write the Hamiltonian that yield two different, inequivalent eigenenergies? The answer to that question is because writing the hamiltonian with $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\epsilon_k/2 & \Delta^* e^{ik\frac{2\pi}{N}} \
\Delta e^{-ik\frac{2\pi}{N}}  & -\epsilon_k/2 \
\end{array}
\right)$$ seems wrong given it yields the incorrect spectrum. Now, that may be trivial to you, but it is an answer to my question.

@Gec From what I understand of your answer, your argument is that both are mathematically equivalent ways of expressing the Hamiltonian, which I agree. Next, you argue that only one of them yields new canonica fermionic operators which is a great point. Perhaps what I mean is that I dont see how that is shown in your answer. Maybe this question is just a lesson that working with Dirac fermions, as opposed to Majorana fermions, is a dumb idea.

This question shows that after formal manipulations, their meaning should be clarified. For brevity, I replace $e^{i\frac{2\pi}{N}k}$ with $e^{ik}$ and $N-k$ with $-k$. In both approaches, the Hamiltonian takes the form
$$
H_{BCS} = \frac12\sum_k\lambda_k(a^\dagger_{k,+}a_{k,+} - a^\dagger_{k,-}a_{k,-}),\tag{*}
$$
where
$$
a^\dagger_{k,\pm} = u_k^{(\pm)}d^\dagger_k + v_k^{(\pm)}d_{-k},\quad
a_{k,\pm} = u_k^{(\pm)*}d_k + v_k^{(\pm)*}d^\dagger_{-k}\tag{1}
$$
with
$$
v_k^{(\pm)} = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda_k\mp\epsilon_k}{2\lambda_k}}
$$
In both cases, by construction, the following standard anticommutation relations are valid:
$$
\{a^\dagger_{k,\pm}, a_{k,\pm}\} = 1, \quad
\{a^\dagger_{k,+},a^\dagger_{k,-}\} = \{a_{k,+},a_{k,-}\}=0, \quad
\{a^\dagger_{k,+},a_{k,-}\} = \{a_{k,+},a^\dagger_{k,-}\}=0
$$
In the first approach, unusual anticommutators also arise. In this case, we have
$$
\lambda_k = \sqrt{\epsilon_k^2+4|\Delta|^2}, \quad 
u_k^{(\pm)} = -\frac{2\Delta^*e^{ik}}{\epsilon_k\mp\lambda_k} v_k^{(\pm)}.
$$
Now it is easy to see that in this case the operators (1) satisfy the following anticommutation relations:
$$
\{a^\dagger_{k,\pm},a^\dagger_{-k,\pm}\} = -(v_k^{(\pm)})^2\frac{4\Delta^*}{\epsilon_k\mp\lambda_k}\cos(k)\neq 0.
$$
This fact means that in this case the operators (1) are not canonical fermion creation-annihilation operators and (*) is not a diagonal form of the Hamiltonian.
In the second approach we have
$$
\lambda_k = \sqrt{\epsilon_k^2+4|\Delta|^2\sin^2(k)}, \quad
u_k^{(\pm)} = -\frac{2i\sin(k)\Delta^*}{\epsilon_k\mp\lambda_k} v_k^{(\pm)}.
$$
Now it is easy to see that in this case operators $a^\dagger_{-k,\pm}$ up to phase multiplier coincide with the operators $a_{k,\mp}$ and thus following anticommutation relations are valid
$$
\{a^\dagger_{k,\pm},a^\dagger_{-k,\pm}\} = 0.
$$
The operators $a^\dagger_{k,+}$, $a_{k,+}$ can be chosen as canonical fermion creation-annihilation operators and from (*) follows the diagonal form of the Hamiltonian
$$
H_{BCS} = \sum_k\lambda_k(a^\dagger_{k,+}a_{k,+}-\frac12).
$$

Great answer, out of curiosity: how did you read off $v_k$ and $u_k$ so easily from the Hamiltonian? Is there a way to see this?

@FriendlyLagrangian Matrix diagonalization in this case means that you replace the $2\times2$ matrix with its "spectral decomposition" $\lambda(e_+ e_+^\dagger - e_- e_-^\dagger)$, where $e_\pm$ are the normalized eigenvectors of the matrix. These eigenvectors have the form $(u^{(\pm)},v^{(\pm)})^{tr}$.

hmm, that's what I thought at first but Mathematica tells me the un-normalized eigenvectors are $v_\pm = (\frac{-\epsilon \pm 2 \lambda}{2\Delta}, 1)$ which I'm having trouble seeing how they are equivalent to yours.

I edited my answer, there was confusion about the factor 1/2. To see the equivalence of the formulas, you may need equalities like $(\lambda\mp\epsilon)/2\Delta = 2\Delta^*/(\lambda\pm\epsilon)$.

I no longer think your answer is correct, see my answer bellow.

This is a general potential problem  with BdG type systems.
When you rewrite a general fermionic BdG  hamiltonian
$$
 \hat H_{\rm Bogoliubov}= a^\dagger_i H_{ij}a_j +\frac 12 \Delta_{ij} a^\dagger_ia^\dagger_j +\frac 12 \Delta^{\dagger}_{ij} a_i a_j
$$
as
$$
 \hat H_{\rm Bogoliubov}= \frac12 \left(\matrix{ a^\dagger_i &a_i}\right)\left(\matrix{ H_{ij}& \phantom {-}\Delta_{ij}\cr                                                                          \Delta^{\dagger}_{ij}& -H^T_{ij}}\right)
                  \left(\matrix{ a_j\cr a^\dagger_j}\right) +\frac 12 {\rm tr}(H).   \nonumber                                                           
$$
it is necessary that the matrix $\Delta_{ij}$ be skew symmetric.  I suspect that one of your two possible forms for the tacit two-by-two matrix matrix involving the indices $k$ and $N-k$ is not skew symmetric, and this leads to the ambiguity.

Would you mind adding a reference for this? What do you mean by "necessary"? As in, "necessary" for what? Note that, as you wrote it, your matrix form is different from mine given I mix $k$ and $N-k$ in my vectors so it's hard to see. Also, what does "BdG" stand for?

There is a discussion on my webpage: https://people.physics.illinois.edu/stone/magnus_berry.pdf

Thank you. I've just understood that it's necessary to preserve Hermicity due to the way you wrote your Hamiltonian. Also, technically speaking, shouldn't $\Delta^\dagger_{ij}$ be written instead as $\Delta^*_{ij}$? I find it confusing to invoque a dagger $\dagger$ on a complex number.

With that understanding and based on your comment, it seems then that one of my Hamiltonians should not be Hermitian?

I should probably have written $(\Delta^\dagger)_{ij}$ to denote the i-j entry in the matrix $\Delta^\dagger$.  It's just that any symmetric part of $\Delta$ is lost in the many-body hamiltonian, but affects the BdG equation.
